# Filtering data over a large combinations of strings

Tags: apache-spark

I have a dataframe(around 50 gb) and 3 lists (a few hundred elements each with total number of combinations 445005).

I need to check if values from column `url` match any of the combinations from the 3 lists and return this combinations. I do it this way.

```
def checkMatch(query1:List[String], query2:List[String], model:List[String]):List[(String, String, String)]= {
for{
x <- query1
y <- query2
z <- model
if(url.contains(x) && url.contains(y) && url.contains(z))
} yield (x,y,z)
}
```

This fails.As in, the aplication doesn't stop, but every task fails with

```
ExecutorLostFailure (executor 26 exited unrelated to the running tasks) Reason: Container container on host: host was preempted.
```

And the application runs until I kill it, without any task completing.

All I found about the error suggests lack of memory. My configs are

```
spark-submit \
--class Main \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode client \
--num-executors 200 \
--executor-cores 10 \
--driver-memory 4G \
--executor-memory 8G \
--files hive-site.xml#hive-site.xml \
--conf spark.task.maxFailures=10 \
--conf spark.executor.memory=8G \
--conf spark.app.name=spark-job \
--conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=4096 \
--conf spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead=2048 \
--conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true \
--conf spark.shuffle.consolidateFiles=true \
--conf spark.broadcast.compress=true \
--conf spark.shuffle.compress=true \
--conf spark.shuffle.spill.compress=true \
--conf spark.network.timeout=10000000 \
--conf spark.executor.heartbeatInterval=10000000 \
```

I tried allocating 2-3 times more memory. It didn't help.

What other solutions are there? Andis lack of memory actually the reason?

Comment: What actual code are you using to apply this function to your dataframe? Otherwise I would probably broadcast the 3 lists in spark and find intersections between the sets, followed by another stage that generates a cartesian product of these reduced sets.

Answer (score 0):

This code takes place on the driver since you aren't specifying any special keywords like map or reduce which is why this is taking so long. Can these lists be flattened into 1 list since their just strings? It'll make map-reduce easier.